# Clarification on rules regarding division of two equations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations

This is going to seem like a highly obscure question because I've likely missed something fairly obvious. Apologies in advance.

Consider the following equations

$$2k+2mk=k$$
$$k+3mk=mk$$

which must be valid for all real values of $k$.

Now obviously the two equations are equivalent and common sense would say that there is only one value of m that satisfies these equations, namely 
$m=-\frac{1}{2}$, which can be obtained by combining the two equations using addition or simply solving one equation.

However, if I divide equation 1 by equation 2, or vice versa, I end up with a quadratic which has solutions $m=-\frac{1}{2}, m=1$. Clearly, the latter is incorrect.

Could someone please clarify why these equations (or any equations two equations of the same sort) cannot be divided? Addition is possible because you're doing the same thing to both sides of whichever equation when you combine them. Should division not also work, as the ratios obtained would be equal?

The topic area is linear transformations, but I'm looking for a more general answer.

Comment: The equations are *not* identical, though they might be equivalent. Either way, you’re potentially dividing by zero.

Comment: Think of $x = 1$ After squaring both sides we have $x^2= 1$ which has two solutions $(\pm 1)$ The fact is that squaring or submitting to nonlinear operations we can preserve the equality but we can introduce also extraneous solutions...

Comment: Thanks, I've made the correction.

Comment: @amd In my experience, dividing by zero usually eliminates a solution, not add an extra one! That is partly why I am confused.

Comment: @CesarEo Thanks, that example makes sense. Though when should division be avoided? Sometimes it does work. Consider if instead of $k$ and $mk$ on the RHS of the equations, you have $t$ and $mt$ where $t$ can be treated like $k$. Then you have two equations which are not necessarily equivalent and, according to my notes, division to obtain two solutions is acceptable.

Comment: @s.xw Regarding the division by zero point: in fact, in this example, dividing by zero is eliminating solutions, not adding extra ones! Considering the system of equations in the variables $(m,k)$, in addition to $(m,k) = (-\frac12,k)$, which is a valid solution for any $k$, the solution $(m,0)$ is valid for any $m$. By dividing the two equations you eliminate all the solutions $(m,0)$ _except_ the $(1,0)$ solutions.

Comment: Note that after the division you follow with a multiplication...

Comment: @Y.Forman That is an interesting way to think about it. The bit about valid solution for any k has helped me understand a bit better. The question asks me to find values of m for which the line $y=mx$ is a line of invariant points under a given linear transformation. So I need values of m which work for any $k$. Also, in this case, $k=0$ corresponds to the origin, which is always invariant under any linear transformation, so our solution should feature any $m$ as a possible solution for $k=0$.

Comment: http://mathonweb.com/help_ebook/html/equations_3.htm Unfortunately, this page says that "often, there is no way to avoid introducing extraneous solutions,". Checking the validity of any solutions after multiplying/dividing is probably the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now obviously the two equations are equivalent

They are indeed equivalent, so you can ignore the second equation, and focus on just the first one:

$$
2k+2mk=k \quad\iff\quad 2mk+2k-k=0 \quad\iff\quad (2m+1)k=0
$$

The latter can only hold true for *all* values of $\,k\,$ iff the LHS is the zero polynomial i.e.$\,2m+1=0\,$.

> Could someone please clarify why these equations (or any equations two equations of the same sort) cannot be divided?

Because, in general, "conflating" several equations into one is prone to introducing extraneous solutions. Simple example, similar to OP's case, where of course the *only* actual solution is $\,x=1\,$:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
x &= 1 \\
2x &= x+1
\end{align}
\end{cases}
\;\;\implies\;\;
 x \cdot 2 x = 1 \cdot (x+1) \;\;\implies\;\; 2x^2 - x - 1 = 0 \;\;\implies\;\; x \in \{\color{red}{-\frac{1}{2}}, 1\}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$6k+6mk = 3k $$
$$ 2k + 6mk = 2mk  $$
subtract
$$  4k = (3-2m)k  $$
$$  (2m+1) k = 0.  $$
when $k$ is not zero, we need $m = -1/2$

Better not to divide anything here

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply the equations after dividing both sides by k:
$(2 + 2m)(1 + 3m) = m$

$6m^2 + 7m + 2 = 0$

$m = \frac{-1}{2}$ and $m = \frac{-2}{3}$

which both work for $(2 + 2m)(1 + 3m) = m$

However, factoring $(2 + 2m)(1 + 3m) = m$ back to separate equations can result in more than one outcome

$(2 + 2m) = 1$ and $(1 + 3m) = m$ where $m = \frac{-1}{2}$ works for the original equations

and $(2 + 2m) = -m$ and $(1 + 3m) = -1$ where $m = \frac{-2}{3}$ works for a different set.